# Редактирование docx в UITextView

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, uitextview

Ребята, я получаю от сервера Docx, мне надо с ним работать, менять размер текста и так далее.

Вопрос: как конвертировать Docx, чтоб получилось работать с текстом в UITextView, ну а потом вернуть это обратно?

Comment: я бы отказался от такого извращения )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал обратить внимание на [WordSDK](http://wordsdk.com). UITextView не может работать с .doc или .docx.

Answer (score 0):

Найти библиотеку для работы с docx и использовать её для произведения манипуляций с файлом.
docx это не просто текстовый файлик.